# Почему ошибки скрипта выводятся в консоль Unity?

Tags: unity3d, консоль, вывод

Я перешёл с MonoDevelop на Visual Studio Code при помощи VSCode.
Среда не видит ошибку:
[image: Среда не видит ошибку]

А Unity видит:
[image: Unity видит]

ВОПРОС: **Почему это так и как сделать наоборот?**
Вот мои настройки VSCode и External Tools:
[image: Настройки VSCode]
[image: Настройки External Tools]

Answer (score 1):

Потому что VScode & MonoDevelop это ухудшенные версии visual studio,в вс коде удобно переходить по ссылкам объекта в те места где он используется(пкм -> Find all references).Если хотите видеть ошибки в среде,то используйте visual studio,иначе изменив скрипт сохраните его и чекайте ошибки в Unity

Answer (score 1):

Трансляция ошибок связана с установками в плагине Unity, который ставится для Visual Studio.

Если не ошибаюсь, это можно поменять. Зайдите в Средства => Параметры => Инструменты для Unity (у вас ведь русский язык, вроде включен). Туда выведены все настройки плагина и есть поле вроде "Потоковая передача ошибок". Скорее всего оно поможет.

Comment: Если я правильно понял и эти настройки нужно поменять в среде, то там нет пункта "Средства", а Code => Параметры ведут к Параметры / Сочетания клавиш / Расширения раскладки клавиатуры /  Фрагменты кода пользователю / Цветовая тема / Тема значка файла (показал бы скриншот, но его нельзя прикреплять к комментариям). Отсюда "Параметры" ведут к обычным параметрам среды, и там нет "Инструменты для Unity".

Comment: @Николай, мой косяк) не обратил внимания, что у вас VS code, а не студия. Инструменты Unity должны в настройках Tools быть. Не знаю, как их тут перевели.